# SHA256 signed drivers not working in Win7 64 Bit

Tags: windows-7, driver

I signed .cat,.sys files using the SHA256 algorithm and these files successfully installed in Win 7 32 bit Embedded OS, but not working in Win7 64 Bit Enterprise edition.

Showing an error like

> "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required
>   for this device. A recent hardware or software change might have
>   installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might
>   be malicious software from an unknown source. (Code 52)".

I already installed the Microsoft patch 'KB3033929-x64' in Win 7 64 bit machine.

Comment: Have you also installed this update? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2921916/the-untrusted-publisher-dialog-box-appears-when-you-install-a-driver-i

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

Comment: Yes I installed the update from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2921916/the-untrusted-publisher-dialog-box-appears-when-you-install-a-driver-i , but getting the same error.